# How to add panning to chart in chartjs?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have created a bar chart with chartjs. I am also using chartjs-plugin-zoom. I have tried several ways but can’t find a way to add panning functionality to chart. Does anyone know how can I add this?

Here is my code:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
                labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5...],
                datasets: [{
                        label: '# of Votes',
                        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2...]
                }]
        },
        options: {
                zoom: {
                        enabled: true,
                        mode: 'x',
                }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**ꜰɪʀꜱᴛ**

add **[hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/)** to your project :

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.min.js"></script>
```

**ꜱᴇᴄᴏɴᴅ**

enable **pan** option for your chart, like so :

```
options: {
   pan: {
      enabled: true,
      mode: 'x',
   },
   ...
}
```

see **[demo on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pfd2on55/)**

Comment: Be sure to include hammer before chartjs and chartjs zoom plugin

Comment: I would like to implement auto panning, is there a way to do it by code?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this [plugin](https://github.com/jjppof/chartjs-plugin-zoom-pan-select). See the [example](https://jjppof.github.io/chartjs-plugin-zoom-pan-select/example/index).

Basically you need to import and initialize it. By default, if you hold shift and drag the chart, it will pan, but you can also set a custom input trigger.

Comment: Thanks but this one not working on touch screens with the two-finger pan.